# Stock splits performance R

Tags: r, data-science, quantmod, stocks

I need to evaluate the post split stock performance with the quantmod package in R for NYSE,AMEX,NASDAQ. My problem is that I'm only able to look up specific symbols ( getSymbols()), but I need to separate my data into non splitting firms and splitting firms, to compare them. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this for the last 25 years ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you’re asking for a resource which is not on stackoverflow. The site is not intended to find people to help hunt for references. Maybe you could first find a data source with the splitting information that you need and then try to join the two. You could then posted my specific question after you get started.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `quantmod` package, you can use getSplits() function to determine which splits a stock has had within a certain timeframe. Since you're dealing with a large number of stocks, you can use a custom function to get what you want.

```
getSymbolSplit <- function(symbol,xts,date) {
  splitCheck <- getSplits(symbol,from = date)
  if(anyNA(splitCheck, recursive = FALSE)){
    xts$Split <- 0
  } else {
    xts$Split <- 1
  }
  return(xts)
}
```

Once you have that function, you can quickly add a split to the existing stocks data. Example:

```
getSymbols('GOOG')
GOOG <- getSymbolSplit('GOOG',GOOG,'1993-01-01')
```

The getSymbols() function creates the xts named GOOG, so our function checks if any splits have happened since 1993-01-01 (yes) and adds a column `Split` with the value of 1.

```
getSymbols('REGN')
REGN <- getSymbolSplit('REGN',REGN,'1993-01-01')
```

Same deal, but REGN has had no splits since 1993 and the column has a value of 0.

Now you have a clear binary variable for grouping between firms that have had a split in your given timeframe.

As a warning, I encountered a problem with BRK-A. R does not normally permit names that include a '-', and the function breaks when trying to pass an xts named BRK-A. If you have stocks that use a - in their symbol, I recommend you rename them before using them. This function is not the only place where the dash could cause problems.

Comment: This doesnt work .. i tried to use it with BHB                                     
getSymbols('BHB')
BHB <- getSymbolSplit('BHB',BHB,'1993-01-01')    

But there isnt a Value 1 in the added column where a split original occured
It begins at 2007-01-01

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo. The line after `} else {` should say `xts$Split <- 1`

Comment: Please show me your code, and the output from running it. For example, using pastebin.com

Comment: Isn't this working as expected? Google had a split in 2014, so the result is that the split column shows 1. Now it is incredibly easy to distinguish stocks which split or didn't.

Comment: yeah but i have a 1 for every single column, that means that google had a stock split on every single day , that cant be true

Comment: Ok you never asked for a distinction between which days have the stock splits. You said that you wanted to have a way to separate stocks with a split vs stocks without a split. If you need the days of splits, then you can just use the built in getSplits() function.